# Mismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF>

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Ok, so I am trying to run this piece of code:

```
%%spark

spark.sql(f'''select t2.ANOT_PDA_PRD
         ,t2.VLR_PDA_PRD AS MAX_VLR_PDA
         ,(CASE t1.cd_gr_mdld_prd_pd
                WHEN 7 THEN t3.DEF_B4
                WHEN 8 THEN t3.DEF_B4
                WHEN 9 THEN t3.DEF_B4
                WHEN 10 THEN t3.DEF_B5
                WHEN 11 THEN t3.DEF_B4
                WHEN 12 THEN t3.DEF_B5
                WHEN 13 THEN t3.DEF_B4
                WHEN 14 THEN t3.DEF_B4
                WHEN 15 THEN t3.DEF_B5
                WHEN 16 THEN t3.DEF_B4
                WHEN 17 THEN t3.DEF_B4
                WHEN 18 THEN t3.DEF_B4
                WHEN 22 THEN t3.DEF_B5
                ELSE 0 END) AS TMP_QUALI
          ,T3.ANOT_PDA_CLI
          from temp_vars_qlt as t1
          left join temp_vars_qlt as t2
          on t1.dt_mvtc = t2.dt_mvtc and t1.cd_cli = t2.cd_cli and T1.cd_gr_mdld_prd_pd=t2.cd_gr_mdld_prd_pd
          left join temp_vars_qlt as t3
          on t1.dt_mvtc = t3.dt_mvtc and t1.cd_cli = t3.cd_cli
          where t1.dt_mvtc between({data_inicial} , {data_final})
          ''').createOrReplaceTempView("temp_safras_qlt_aux")
```

But I got the following error:

```
SparkStatementException: "\nmismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF>(line 19, pos 14)\n\n== SQL 
==\nselect t2.ANOT_PDA_PRD\n             ,t2.VLR_PDA_PRD AS MAX_VLR_PDA\n             ,(CASE 
t1.cd_gr_mdld_prd_pd\n                    WHEN 7 THEN t3.DEF_B4\n                    WHEN 8 
THEN t3.DEF_B4\n  .................
```

whi A LOT of other lines, but altough is not readable entirely, I believe the important part is in the first line.
But I do not know what `"\nmismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF>` was supposed to mean anyway.

So, the question is simple: what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[`between`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#between) syntax is `BETWEEN 2 AND 5`, try to change yours to `between {data_inicial} and {data_final}`

Comment: Yes, I tried. It was this syntax before. But, in that case it gives `cannot resolve t1.dt_mvtc >= ((2017 - 1) - 31) due to data type mismatch: differing types (date and int)`. But I double checked and { data_inicial} and {data_final} are strings, then I tried to change with `to_date()` but it still raises the same error

Comment: so that's something you have to fix, as you were saying `t1.dt_mvtc` is date, `data_inicial` and `data_final` are string, and the error you see is int?